# Create a element embedded in a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a text input in a form with a class = 'myclass'

[image]

And I want to create a javascript that take this element and add a button with a link next to the input in the same space that the previous input take

[image]

I'm trying this

```js
var createLink = function() {
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    var nameInput = document.getElementsByClassName("input-class");
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>';

    serieInput.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper,serieInput);

    wrapper.appendChild(serieInput);
    wrapper.appendChild(btn);
};
```

but I can't catch the parent Node.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please try to add the code which you have tried.

Comment: Do you want to add the button when any event occur?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `serieInput` and `nameInput` should be the same in your code?

If you replace the input with the wrapper it will no longer exist to be appended into the wrapper.

What you could do is:

1. Get the current parent and next sibling of the input.
2. Append the input to the wrapper, which will move the input out of its current parent.
3. Append the button to the wrapper.
4. If the original input had a sibling append the wrapper before that. If not append it to the end of the parent.

e.g.

```js
var createLink = function() {
  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  var nameInput = document.getElementsByClassName("input-class")[0];
  var btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.innerHTML = '<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a>';

  var parent = nameInput.parentNode;
  var next = nameInput.nextSibling;
  
  wrapper.appendChild(nameInput);
  wrapper.appendChild(btn);

  if (next) {
    parent.insertBefore(wrapper, next);
  } else {
    parent.appendChild(wrapper);
  }
};

createLink();
```

```html
<div>
<input class="input-class">
</div>
```